# Android app and Scala. This fragment should provide a default constructor

Tags: android, eclipse, scala

I'm trying to make Android application in Scala. I'm not good at it and I didn't find good tutorials for it. So, I'm using tutorial for Android+Java and trying to do things from tutorial in Scala. And I have a problem with Fragment. Fragment code looks like this:

```
class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
  override def onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: Bundle) : View = {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)          
  }
}
```

And the errors what I got are:

```
- This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no 
 arguments) (com.example.myscalaandroidproject.MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment)
- Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus 
 Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead
```

Obviously I need to make a default constructor. It is probably lame question, but how can I do it right?

Comment: The Scala class you listed already has a default constructor (since it has no parameters after the class name).

Comment: @IulianDragos  I see. What shall I do with the errors? Can I just ignore them? Eclipse suggest "disable check in this file". Is this the right way to solve the problem?

Comment: @IulianDragos You know, it probably was some eclipse bug or something. I just make another project, did exactly the same, but this time it's working. Can you write again but in answer section, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: That may be caused by proguard. Make sure to keep Fragment constructors in proguard config file.

Comment: I don't have experience with Android application development. @far.be might be right, so if it's because of proguard, he should be the one to get the reputation points. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public PlaceholderFragment ()
{

}
```

And if you want to pass data, you can't use a constructor since Android can destroy and recreate it with the default constructor. You need to use arguments, which are kept when recreating a fragment.

```
public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int id) {
    PlaceholderFragment myFragment = new PlaceholderFragment ();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("id", id);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

Comment: I knew that it is possible to write apps with Scala and Java at the same time. But I don't think i can insert Java code in Scala class... Or can I?

Comment: I don't know what Scala is, but it seems that there should be some translation from java to Scala possible, seeing that your `onCreateView` is really similar with the Java version.